# Saving and Displaying the results of long running tasks at the SAME time using BASH

Tags: bash, shell

I have some long running tasks (5-10 hours), which print the results into the shell. 
So far so good.

But I'd like to show the current output AND save the results in a file at the same time.

Something like

```
./myApplication | tee output.txt
```

is not sufficient, since it does not display the current output. Seeing the current output would be nice, to get an idea how long the current task still takes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `tee output.txt` should output the executed commands on the shell on the fly, it doesn't wait for the whole script to be over.

Comment: You `myApplication` may also be buffering output if output is not a terminal like the pipe. Or maybe it's actually producing a different one.

Comment: Good to know that 'tee' is not waiting for the termination of 'myApplication'.I'll check if it's a buffering issue. Thank you

Comment: If you run your script on a tar server, then you might not be able to see the result, in that case, you can use "until" loop to check for a particular keyword and tail -Nsomenumber file.log within the loop.